# iPhone Weird Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am getting the following error:

```
[CALayer superlayer]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb00afb0
```

However it isn't giving me a stack trace when it breaks so i have no idea where it is doing this.

Has any one else ever had this error or advise me some better debugging techniques so I can further investigate?

Comment: Have you tried with NSZombieEnabled? I guess it can trace where exactly your code is breaking.

Comment: This error is not weird, [but common](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=message+sent+to+deallocated+instance)

Comment: I do agree, as the error was not giving a stack trace, that's why I suggested for NSZombie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over-releasing something. You should probably turn on a debugger to trace the error, or even try running Build/Build and Analyze. That can sometimes catch it.

Answer (score 3):

Typing bt (for backtrace) in the console after it crashes will let you see the stack trace as well.  This is often helpful in tracking down some of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

That typically means something is getting over-released. Look at your alloc/init lines, look for places autoreleased objects (particularly UIView subclasses) are getting called perhaps after their pool has drained, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) to find the object, that got over-released.